# Error function of ngx toastr is not showing error message

Tags: angular, toastr

When I call toastr.error and pass message then it is not showing message although toastr appears. 
But for toastr.success it is working fine.
Please help me how I can fix it.
Uploaded screenshot of the same.

[image]

Comment: How do you suppose anyone can tell how to fix the code if you don't show it?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to import on **app.module.ts**

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```